# Listen to radio buttons on change and when the document is ready with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I'm searching everywhere and I can only find how to make a radio button listener or how to check if it's checked on `ready` but never both, like I need:

When I edit an object in a form, depending on what was selected in a radio group a `div` should be visible or hidden. And when the user changes that, it should appear/disappear again.

I could initialize the correct state by adding a *hidden* class on the server side to the `div` but then I would have to program all my dependencies in php AND jQuery since I'm not using AJAX - that doesn't make sense to me.

I looked in the jQuery website for a best practice - it seemed to be [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/#don-39-t-use-trigger-simply-to-execute-specific-functions).
But I don't understand how I should do it in my case - the `$(this)` seems not to be working and I don't exactly know why. Because I'm referencing a function outside of the event?

```js
var fieldHider = function (turnOn, toggleFields, fadeIn) {
    var visibilityAction;
    if (turnOn) {
        visibilityAction = (fadeIn) ? "fadeIn" : "show";
    } else {
        visibilityAction = (fadeIn) ? "fadeOut" : "hide";
    }
    $(toggleFields)[visibilityAction]();
};

var translatorRadioChanged = function (event) {
    var isOn = ($(this).val() === '1');
    var fading = (event) ? true : false;
    fieldHider(isOn,'label[for="translator"]', fading);
};

var translatorRadioNames = "translatorNeeded";

$(function () {
    $("input[name='" + translatorRadioNames + "']").change(translatorRadioChanged);
    translatorRadioChanged();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="translatorNeeded">
Translator needed
<input type="radio" value="1" name="translatorNeeded">
Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" name="translatorNeeded">
No -> Div below should be hidden!
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label for="translator">
<label class="lcapp-label clearfix" for="translator">
Translator Name + Language
<input type="text" name="name" size="5">
<input type="text" name="lang" size="5">
</label>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function with 2 different contexts.

Try just triggering the change event on the matching checked input when page loads and after the change listener is assigned

Change

```
$("input[name='" + translatorRadioNames + "']").change(translatorRadioChanged);
translatorRadioChanged();
```

To

```
$("input[name='" + translatorRadioNames + "']")
       // assign event listener
       .change(translatorRadioChanged)
       // trigger the event on checked one if it exists
       .filter(':checked').change();
```

Now the function will be called in the context of the event handler and will have the right context for `this`

Comment: I like your answer but I just noticed that when I execute this code with your change it fires the `translatorRadioChanged` function twice - first with true and then with false. What's that about?

Comment: will fire for each element in the collection. I really didn't analyze closely what is inside the handler...was more focused on the context

Comment: Another way would be `.change(translatorRadioChanged).filter(':checked').change();`

Comment: that was it, thanks - I didn't know about the filter method and now I understand your solution better, it's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` in `ready` is the `window`.

change it to look for the `:checked` radio's value:-

```js
var fieldHider = function (turnOn, toggleFields, fadeIn) {
    var visibilityAction;
    if (turnOn) {
        visibilityAction = (fadeIn) ? "fadeIn" : "show";
    } else {
        visibilityAction = (fadeIn) ? "fadeOut" : "hide";
    }
    $(toggleFields)[visibilityAction]();
};

var translatorRadioChanged = function (event) {
    var isOn = ($("input[name='" + translatorRadioNames + "']:checked").val() === '1');
    var fading = (event) ? true : false;
    fieldHider(isOn,'label[for="translator"]', fading);
};

var translatorRadioNames = "translatorNeeded";

$(function () {
    $("input[name='" + translatorRadioNames + "']").change(translatorRadioChanged);
    translatorRadioChanged();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="translatorNeeded">
Translator needed
<input type="radio" value="1" name="translatorNeeded">
Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" name="translatorNeeded">
No -> Div below should be hidden!
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label for="translator">
<label class="lcapp-label clearfix" for="translator">
Translator Name + Language
<input type="text" name="name" size="5">
<input type="text" name="lang" size="5">
</label>
</label>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough with my question I think. I don't want to reference the radios with a string in my code again because I think it looks bad and I want to find a smoother way with which I can also reuse my `translatorRadioChanged()` for all other radios as well by replacing `'label[for="translator"]'` with a variable later.